# How to Upload Array of files in Vue.js and Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to upload multiple files in Laravel and vue.js but I don't know what's the actual way that I have missed it. can you please help me?

Thanks

### Vue file

```
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
    <label>Course Module PDF</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" @change="onChangeFiles" />
  </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      files: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleSubmit() {
      let data = new FormData();
      data.append("files[]", this.files);

      axios.post("/add-course", data, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
  })
        .then(() => {
          this.isLoading = false;
          console.log('Success');
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
          
          
        }
    },
    },
    onChangeFiles(event) {
      let file = event.target.files[0];
      this.files.push(file);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

### controller code

```
$files = $request->files;

  if (count($files) > 0) {

      foreach ($files as $file) {
          $ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
          $name = time().'-'.".".$ext;
          $upload_path = 'backend/files/';
          $upload_url = $upload_path.$name;
          $file->move(public_path($upload_path),$upload_url);
      }

  }

  return "Success";
```

Nothing is happening

template screenshot:

http://prntscr.com/111fd8j

Comment: do `console.log(this.files)` before submitting form, if files are being pushed or not there. in `onChangeFiles()`

Comment: http://prntscr.com/111g0f7

Comment: now check request with `dd($request)` before `$files = $request->files;`

Comment: http://prntscr.com/111gd68

Comment: you need to check files array with foreach loop. in foreach loop check file values

Comment: It's showing blank. can you provide the correct code that how I could check with foreach ?

Comment: I don't see in your code where you actually send the form data to the server. It looks like you append it then nothing else in the submit handler

Comment: @silversunhunter I send the the data with axios but I have to foret to add here the code ``` handleSubmit() {
      let data = new FormData();
      data.append("files[]", this.files);

      axios.post("/add-course", data, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
  })
        .then(() => {
          this.isLoading = false;
          console.log('Success');
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
          
          
        }
    }, 
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the fileName format when you trying to save it in your backend and exactly in the loop:

```
$upload_path = public_path('upload'); // there is no need to define variable in each loop iteration 
foreach ($request->file("files") as $file) {
        $file_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $generated_new_name = time() . '-'. $file_name .'.'. $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $file->move($upload_path, $generated_new_name);
    }
```

The problem is that the backend overrides the file because it has the same name because of the time() function so all the files will be created at the same time and all files coming from your frontend will have the same name and for sure only the last file will be saved, so you will think that the frontend just send one file but if you trying to do sizeOf($request->file("files")) it will give you the number of files that has been sent....

Hopefully, this will solve your problem...